# Transferring from a Schengen country to the UK (which is a non Schengen country) at Schiphol

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, ams, klm

I'm planning to take a flight from Milan (Italy) to Aberdeen (UK), with one stop at Schiphol. Both flights are operated by KLM and I have 1h25m available to change planes, I'm only carrying an hand luggage and it seems from their website that I have to go through passport check (since I don't have a passport I'll be using my ID card which is valid for travels inside the EU) but not security again.

Is the above correct? Is 1h25m enough to change planes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Passengers who arrive at Schiphol from a country with trusted airport security do not have to pass through transfer security. This includes all EU countries.

You'll need to pass through the Schengen outbound border control, but that is quick and painless for EU nationals.

1h25 will be plenty if your inbound flight is not too much delayed.

Answer (score 2):

KLM wouldn't sell the ticket if they didn't think it was possible. Below is from their website about transferring at Schiphol. It should take you about 40 minutes. Although time might be added for outbound border control. This is usually pretty quick from my experience travelling to the UK while connecting in Europe.

> The standard transfer time at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol to a flight
>   within Europe is 40 minutes and 50 minutes for an intercontinental
>   flight.
>
> If you are travelling to/from Schengen and non-Schengen countries, you
>   should count on having to go through additional security checks and
>   customs inspections. These can substantially extend the time it takes
>   to complete your transfer procedure.
>
> If you do not make your next flight because of a lack of time, you
>   will automatically be booked on another flight. Your baggage will be
>   relabelled and you will not have to retrieve it or check in for the
>   new flight. Your new flight details can be retrieved and you can print
>   out your new boarding pass at a kiosk.

[KLM website](https://www.klm.com/travel/gb_en/prepare_for_travel/at_the_airport/connections/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The standard transfer time at Amsterdam Airport Schiphol to a flight within Europe is 40 minutes and 50 minutes for an intercontinental flight. 50 minutes is the minimum connecting time (MCT) at Schiphol Airport. Having said that, 1h25m is sufficient and You should be fine as long as your inbound flight is not delayed.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to have a biometric passport: it really speed up all passport queues, and it helps you go to other countries. So if you think in future you need it, try to have it also for this travel.

I think 1h25 is usually enough: Schiphol is a convenient airport for transit. I think in 15/20 minutes normal walk you can reach all gates from any gate (worst case). For European flights, gates usually closes 10/15 minutes before departure time. So you still have enough time for passport control and shopping.

But last week I had a similar situation (1:35 minutes), and because delays on first flight, I was denied to board on the second flight. So be prepared to go to a transfer desk and get a new flight.